# Spring WS Dynamic WSDL from xsds

Tags: java, spring, web-services, wsdl, spring-ws

Got `CommonsXsdSchemaCollection` with `inline = true` with one xsd which `xs:include` others. It has `targetNamespace`. Almost all of included xsds has the same namespace, but one xsd doesn't have `targetNamespace`. Xsd without `targetNamespace` have `xs:attributeGroup` with name and elements which refs to it. But when spring tries to inline this xsd exception appears: `Attribute group must have ref name set`. I debugged the source code of: `org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core` and I see that `xs:attributeGroup` element with name gets `targetNamespace` from xsd which includes it, and `xs:attributeGroup` with ref doesn't get this namespace, so this error appears.
Question is:
 How to get rid off this error? Is there a way to put `targetNamespace` to all included elements? Or run this inlining without `targetNamespace` in some schemas. Or any other ways?